# ViewModel and leanback fragments

Tags: android-tv, leanback

How can I use `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel` with leanback fragments? For example `GuidedStepFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment` which cannot be used in ViewModel instance creation via `ViewModelProviders.of(fragment).get(viewModelClass)` because method `ViewModelProviders.of` requires `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.
Am I something missing or ViewModel can't be used for leanback fragments?

Leanback developers, hello? Why are you extending `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `GuidedStepSupportFragment` (extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) in `leanback` starting from `27.1.0`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! As for now we are at 26.1.0 and I didn't see that. I tried to check for latest support lib version but didn't search for other fragments.